# how to calculate Otsu threshold in 1D

Tags: threshold

I'm trying to identify bimodal distributions in my analytical chemistry data. Each data set is a list of 3~70 retention times for a particular compound from the GC-MS. RTs for some compound are bimodally distributed where the library searches have assigned the same identity to two or more different features in the data with different RTs. This is quite common for isomers and other compound pairs with very similar mass spectra.
Eg. here's a histogram of RTs for one compound showing bimodal distribution. 
[image: RT histogram]

I want to calculate the Otsu threshold to try and define bimodal data (there's also multimodal distributions but one step at a time). I'm struggling to understand [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) on the calculations but the text indicates that the threshold can be found by finding the minimum intraclass variance. So I've tried computing this from a list of the RTs as follows:

```
a = list(d['Component RT'])
n = len(a)
b = [a.pop(0)]

varA = []
varB = []

for i in range(1,n-2):
    b.append(a.pop(0))
    varA.append(statistics.stdev(a)**2)
    varB.append(statistics.stdev(b)**2)
```

Am I right in thinking that if I plot the sum of the variances for the above data I should be able to identify the Otsu threshold as the minimum?
[image: summed variances]

In this example the threshold is obvious and there's about 35 values to work from. For most compounds there's fewer values (typically <15) and the data may be less well defined. Is this even the right threshold to use? The Wikipedia article on modality indicates a whole bunch of other tests for multimodality.

Answer (score 0):

result is simillar to  opencv thresh by OTSU.

```
uchar OTSU(const std::vector<uchar>& input_vec) {
// normalize input to 0-255 if needed
int count[256];
double u0, u1, u;
double pixelSum0, pixelSum1;
int n0, n1;
int bestThresold = 0, thresold = 0;
double w0, w1;
double variable = 0, maxVariable = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    count[i] = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < input_vec.size(); i++) {
count[int(input_vec[i])] ++;
}

for (thresold = 0; thresold < 256; thresold++) {
    n0 = 0;
    n1 = 0;
    w0 = 0;
    w1 = 0;
    pixelSum0 = 0;
    pixelSum1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < thresold; i++) {
        n0 += count[i];
        pixelSum0 += i * count[i];
    }
    for (int i = thresold; i < 256; i++) {
        n1 += count[i];
        pixelSum1 += i * count[i];
    }

    w0 = double(n0) / (input_vec.size());
    w1 = double(n1) / (input_vec.size());
    u0 = pixelSum0 / n0;
    u1 = pixelSum1 / n1;
    u = u0 * w0 + u1 * w1;
    variable = w0 * pow((u0 - u), 2) + w1 * pow((u1 - u), 2);

    if (variable > maxVariable) {
        maxVariable = variable;
        bestThresold = thresold;
    } 
} 
return bestThresold;}
```

ref :https://github.com/1124418652/edge_extract/blob/master/edge_extract/OTSU.cpp